# Como utilizar salts e hashs com PHP?

Tags: php, segurança, hash, senhas

Seguinte pessoal, tenho que fazer um sistema de cadastro e login de usuários, mas queria aumentar a segurança desse sistema utilizando salts nas senhas, alguém poderia me mostrar um exemplo simples sobre isso?

Comment: Leia as respostas desta pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3571/qual-o-melhor-jeito-de-fazer-um-sistema-de-login-em-senha-com-php/4479#4479

Comment: dá uma olhada aqui ..: http://br.phptherightway.com/. Ele fala sobre alguns frames pra isso

Answer (score 5):

#### Passado

Recomendo que utilize a solução que o [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/) e o [Drupal](https://drupal.org) usam. Eu acho que se eles usam, então deve ser seguro o suficiente. Você não acha?

Chama-se [**Portable PHP password hashing framework**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/).

O *hash* que essa solução gera já contém o *salt* embutido - você não precisa se preocupar com isso, mas recebe o benefício. Ou seja, você estará efetivamente usando *salts* e *hashs*, aumentando a segurança, e de uma maneira extremamente simples - mais simples do que eu acho que você queria ver numa resposta. Se quiser entender mais sobre os bastidores da coisa, então fique à vontade para pesquisar mais. Eu só vou mostrar como Wordpress e Drupal fazem.

Para gerar o *hash*:

```
require( 'PasswordHash.php' );
$hasher = new PasswordHash();
$passHash = $hasher->HashPassword( 'senha' );
```

Pronto! Na variável `$passHash` você tem agora a senha "salteada" e "hasheada", prontinha para ir pro banco de dados.

Veja que interessante: cada vez que você chama a função `HashPassword` para a **mesma  senha**, ela vai te retornar um **hash diferente**. Isso acontece inclusive porque o *salt* está armazenado junto o próprio *hash* na *string* que é retornada.

Portanto, você não tem como verificar depois se o usuário está informando a senha certa fazendo algo assim, como usualmente faria com um *hash* fraco como o **MD5**:

```
if ( $hasher->HashPassword( 'senha' ) == $passHash_obtido_do_BD )
```

Porque isso não funciona? Não funciona porque, como foi dito, cada vez o *hash* gerado é diferente!

Mas a solução para verificar se a senha informada é correta é igualmente simples e fácil:

```
require( 'PasswordHash.php' );
$hasher = new PasswordHash();
if ( $hasher->CheckPassword( 'senha', $passHash_obtido_do_BD ) )
```

E então? Para que complicar mais se você pode oferecer uma solução tão boa quanto a que o Wordpress usa, nos seus projetos e para os seus clientes?

Confira você mesmo a função **wp_check_password** do Wordpress, para não dizer que estou inventando:

- https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1536

---

#### Presente

CONSIDERAÇÃO IMPORTANTE: um sistema de autenticação e autorização, pensando desde a interface, acesso a banco de dados, login e logout, cookies, vulnerabilidades, *et cetera*, envolvem mais **um monte de questões** não abordadas aqui. Você, felizmente, fez uma questão bem objetiva sobre apenas um ponto específico: como "temperar" a senha com *salts* e *hashear* a mesma? Afinal, não queremos armazená-la em *plain text* no banco de dados; queremos efetivamente dificultar tanto que as senhas sejam "quebradas" e descobertas; queremos deixar tão difícil que nem nós mesmos tenhamos como saber as senhas. A solução acima focaliza isso, e somente isso, trazendo uma ferramenta prática, que você pode usar já, obter os benefícios, e da maneira mais simples possível. Aí você pode prosseguir satisfeito pro próximo item do quebra-cabeças.

---

#### Futuro

Todo meu bla-bla-blá acima vai logo virar coisa do passado, já que a partir do PHP versão 5.5 teremos a mesma funcionalidade já embutida.

A função [`password_hash`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.password-hash.php) equivale à `HashPassword`, e a função [`password_verify`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.password-verify.php) equivale à `CheckPassword`, exatamente como explicadas acima. Confira a documentação: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.password.php

Eis os exemplos atualizados para o futuro:

```
// Obtendo o hash:
$passHash = password_hash( 'senha' );

// Verificando a senha:
if ( password_verify( 'senha', $passHash_obtido_do_BD ) )
```