# Escolha do método para geração de hash em PHP

Tags: php, segurança, hash, senhas

Minha dúvida começou quando decidi reanalisar o método que estava usando para obter a senha do usuário e armazenar a mesma no Banco de Dados. Após ler [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura), [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5757/como-utilizar-salts-e-hashs-com-php) e [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3571/qual-a-melhor-maneira-de-criar-um-sistema-de-login-com-php/4479#4479) pergunta aqui na rede, além de muitas outras em outras redes, como [essa](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104818/hashing-passwords-in-php) e [essa](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/126367/password-encryption-for-php-5-3-or-should-we-update-to-5-5), algumas dúvidas me surgiram.

Possuímos métodos antigos, porém excelentes até os dias atuais, de se gerar um *hash* para armazenar no *BD*. Também possuímos alguns, que eram considerados ótimos, mas que já estão caindo em desuso (ou pelo menos em conceito) devido a segurança, como é o caso do `md5` e família `sha`.

Também temos novos métodos onde, até onde li, parece ser o mais forte candidato a ser utilizado para a geração de *hash*, inclusive mais recomendado que o próprio `bcrypt` ou `PBKDF2`, que é o caso do `password_*` no `PHP >= 5.5`.

---

Alguns requisitos que observei como ideais na elaboração da *hash* seriam:

- Todo *hash* gerado deve ser criado junto de um *salt*;
- Todo *salt* gerado deve ser único por cliente;
- A função deve ser lenta, para dificultar o ataque de força bruta;

---

Com isso em mente, até onde posso considerar esse pensamento como correto e começar a utilizar apenas o método `password_*`? Ele se enquadraria nos requisitos ideais para geração de *hash*?

O que me chamou a atenção foi também a simplicidade em termos de código de se utilizar `password_*`, pois com poucas linhas de códigos podemos obter o resultado esperado, exemplo:

```
//Gerar um hash
$salt    = $resultadoSalt; //resultado de uma função para obter o salt único
$options = [
    'cost' => 14,
    'salt' => $salt
];
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);

//Validar um hash
if (!password_verify($password, $hash)) return false;
```

Neste caso, armazenar o resultado da função `password_hash` no Banco de Dados já seria suficiente? Ex.: `$2y$14$5e7b5f0ef3cccfac9b902uR4sHJTlTYv3RYt3ApP7PvyTXHmdhN7e` ou algum outro processo seria recomendado?

Lembrando que quaisquer outras considerações acerca do assunto são bem vindas!

Comment: Na verdade, no PHP 7 é considerado obsoleto informar o `salt`, isso é gerado automaticamente pela função. Então, acredito que informar o `salt` não seja a melhor opção. Os critérios que observou está correto, apenas acrescentaria "um": o tempo de uso e popularidade. O bcrypt é antigo (antes de 2000). Existe o scrypt, salvo engano, ele foi publicado em 2009. Justamente por ser recente ainda não é "tão aceito", é necessário que ele resista por mais tempo vivo. Mas, em resposta a pergunta, acredito que seria suficiente. Acho que a função foi criada assim, fácil, para vê se param de usar o MD5. :P

Comment: @Inkeliz O problema do uso do salt gerado pela função é justamente esse, ser aleatório, ou seja, quando o cliente for logar, o salt não será o mesmo gerado quando ele criou a conta, logo o hash seria diferente, não? Pelo menos pelo teste que fiz e pelo que li, essa foi a conclusão.

Comment: Quando usar o `password_verify` não irá comparar uma hash com outra, nem mesmo deve inserir o salt. Então o salt deve ser aleatório,  até mesmo para ser único. O manual do PHP não recomenda que use um salt personalizado ou reinvente a roda para gerar o salt, "It is strongly recommended that you do not generate your own salt for this function.". Experimente remover o `salt` e funcionará da mesma forma, mesmo gerando hash totalmente diferente uma da outra. Como isso funciona estou a espera de alguém responder também. :D

Comment: @Inkeliz vou fazer alguns testes desse modo então, não estou lembrado desses detalhes. O que me deixou confuso foi justo essa frase "não reinvente a roda, já existe muitas opções disponíveis". Mas são tantas, e tantas que dizem ser boas, que não sei de fato qual é a boa! hahaha

Comment: Apenas para responder a questão do `salt`. O `salt` já é armazenado na própria senha, ou um trecho dele. Por exemplo: se o `salt` for de `1234567891234567891234`, a senha de `abc` será `$2y$14$123456789123456789123uqefxzc/iUTZnhJmbDgxEKiWGTixIZu6`. Note que o segundo `$` indica o `cost` (14), em seguida justamente o salt: sendo visivelmente `123456789123456789123`, só faltou o `4`, o ultimo numero, que então sei onde foi parar (mas alterar o ultimo numero do `salt` não muda a hash, então...). De qualquer forma, o salt já está embutido na hash, então, por isso consegue realizar a comparação.

Comment: @Inkeliz Sim, essa lógica eu até havia compreendido. Porém, como o salt não aparece totalmente, imaginei que houvesse algum outro porém.. Mas agora consegui observar de modo diferente essa questão. E presumo eu que isso não tem nenhum impacto no quesito segurança, correto?

Comment: Porque não faz um limite de tentativas por hora? Assim evita bastante a força bruta, caso o hacker exceda esse limite terá que esperar "anos", para voltar a conseguir.

Comment: @Gonçalo isso é um complemento bom pra aplicação, mas não resolve o problema do hash, vide as outras postagens linkadas na própria pergunta. O salt e hash não são só pra evitar acesso à aplicação, e sim para evitar acesso às credenciais mesmo que o atacante consiga uma cópia do DB de senhas.

Comment: Na verdade a pergunta atual parece mais um pedido de confirmação de entendimento, ou mesmo um debate sobre o que já foi postado, do que uma nova dúvida. Quando for assim, recomendo deixar comentário nas postagens originais, que a gente pode tentar complementar, explicar, melhorar etc.

Comment: @Bacco eu entendi sua resposta mais como uma base teórica e explicativa entre os métodos e características de cada um. Enquanto minha dúvida é mais em relação ao uso/segurança aliado a simplicidade de código que o password_* vem oferecendo quando comparado à outros métodos, como o `md5` (gerando um `salt` "manual"), o próprio `PBKDF2` ou outras técnicas.

Comment: Não entenda como uma base teórica só, é pra usar na prática mesmo :) Mas não se prenda só à minha resposta, que é uma adaptação de uma excelente postagem já existente do SO em inglês. Tem uma série de outras informações importantes em outras respostas lá, que são bem interessantes. Sugiro reler tentando entender quais problemas cada técnica tenta resolver, que fica mais fácil de ver quais são os problemas de um md5 (colisão e velocidade, por exemplo). Mas, se conseguir descrever com mais precisão as partes que não entendeu, como eu disse, podemos tentar ajudar.

Comment: Quanto ao password do PHP, pra você saber se ele é "bom o suficiente", é questão de entender os conceitos passados. Eu diria que pra uso normal, com bcrypt, é suficiente pra maior parte dos usos. Mas só você quem pode realmente saber o valor da informação que está sendo protegida e os riscos envolvidos. Segurança não tem "solução pronta" pra todos os casos. Só entendendo mesmo, e se atualizando. Vai ser sempre uma corrida entre defensor e atacante, equilibrada pelo valor da informação. Lembrando que nesse valor pode estar incluida uma senha de terceiros que não deveria, mas pode ser reusada.

Comment: @Bacco sim sim, entendo perfeitamente seu ponto de vista. Talvez essa "visão" que você está tentando me passar não seja tão clara ainda pela minha falta de experiência (pois sou mais do front end - design), mas vou reconsiderar esses últimos tópicos que você apontou e reler com mais calma! =D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Com isso em mente, até onde posso considerar esse pensamento como
>   correto e começar a utilizar apenas o método password_*? Ele se
>   enquadraria nos requisitos ideais para geração de hash?

O objetivo da API de password do PHP é o reaproveitamento do código. Até a versão 7.1 o algoritmo padrão `CRYPT_BLOWFISH`, mas a partir do PHP 7.2 temos um novo algoritmo mais seguro chamado Aragon2 a partir da biblioteca libsodium:

- [libsodium como uma *extension core*](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/libsodium)
- [Inclusão do algoritmo Argon2](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argon2_password_hash) (Incluída a nova constante `PASSWORD_ARGON2I`)

Você já apontou um uso básico da API de [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), porém é recomendado deixar que a função gere automaticamente o *salt* para você. Inclusive, a partir do PHP 7 a opção de fornecer um [*salt* customizado foi descontinuada](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration70.deprecated.php#migration70.deprecated.pwshash-salt-option) pois permitia os desenvolvedores utilizarem *salts* não seguros.

```
// o cost padrão é 10, aumente caso deseje que o hash seja mais demorado
$options = [
    'cost' => 14,
];

$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options);
```

Note que alterei o segundo argumento para a constante `PASSWORD_DEFAULT`. A partir dela será possível usar um novo algoritmo sem alterar sua aplicação. A partir do *hash* gerado o PHP irá conseguir verificar se uma senha confere a partir do [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php):

```
$hash = '$2y$07$BCryptRequires22Chrcte/VlQH0piJtjXl.0t1XkA8pw9dMXTpOq';

if (password_verify('alguma_senha', $hash)) {
    echo 'Passou!';
} else {
    echo 'Senha incorreta.';
}
```

Ao ocorrer uma troca do algoritmo, utilize a função [`password_needs_rehash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-needs-rehash.php) para alterar seu hash para um mais seguro. Essa função pode ser utilizada também caso o *cost* seja aumentado.

```
$password = 'alguma_senha';
// $10 é referente ao cost, que nesse caso é 10
$hash = '$2y$10$YCFsG6elYca568hBi2pZ0.3LDL5wjgxct1N8w/oLR/jfHsiQwCqTS';

// Um cost mais alto foi utilizado
$options = ['cost' => 11];

// Verifica a senha com o hash
if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {

    // O Hash é o mais recente com base nas configs passadas?
    // Imagine que o PASSWORD_DEFAULT foi alterado...
    if (password_needs_rehash($hash, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options)) {

        // Se sim, crie um novo hash dessa senha
        $newHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options);

        // Passos para atualizar o hash no banco
    }

    // Usuário logado
}
```

> Alguns requisitos que observei como ideais na elaboração da hash
>   seriam:
>
> - Todo hash gerado deve ser criado junto de um salt;
> - Todo salt gerado deve ser único por cliente;
> - A função deve ser lenta, para dificultar o ataque de força bruta;

Observando os requisitos, os itens 1 e 2 estão já possuem um *salt* gerado de forma aleatória pelo `password_hash` se nada for enviado nas `options`.

O terceiro item precisa ser avaliado encontrando a relação entre um *cost* que seja demorado de quebrar com força bruta e o tempo de espera de um usuário comum na aplicação. Quanto maior o *cost*, mais demorado será para quebrá-lo, mas também não faça seu usuário esperar 1 minuto para tentar fazer login :)

Em um ataque de força bruta onde o atacante tenha obtido os *hashes* a partir do banco, o que vai atrasar o trabalho dele é o *cost* definido.

Mas no caso de um ataque força bruta a partir de um *endpoint* externo do seu site, você pode aplicar alguma técnica de *throttling*, que consiste em deixar esse processamento mais lento para algumas requisições somente sem afetar a experiência do usuário. Isso é feito inserindo pausas na execução do script por um período de alguns segundos para tentativas de login incorretas, fazendo as requisições demorarem mais.

Outra alternativa é desativar o usuário temporariamente e somente ativar a partir de um outro meio de contato (contato com *service desk*, confirmação por sms ou telefone, *reset* de senha por email, por exemplo).

Resumindo, ao trabalhar com senhas no PHP utilize o `password_*` para:

- Simplificar seu código
- Não ter problemas em futuras migrações
- Possibilidade de alterar o motor de criptografia no futuro de forma transparente para a aplicação

Comment: Na geração de _hash_, onde eu demonstrei com o uso de `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` e você alterou para `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` qual seria o principal motivo? Ou qual melhor opção? Se eu utilizar `bcrypt` eu não consigo utilizar o `password_needs_rehash` futuramente?

Comment: A ideia do password_hash é possibilitar vc trocar o algoritmo de forma simples. `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` e o `PWORD_BCRYPT` hoje são a mesma coisa, mas se no PHP 8, por exemplo o `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` alterar para `PASSWORD_BATATA`, vc ainda estará usando o `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` e precisará alterar seu código para usar o `PASSWORD_BATATA`

Comment: @CelsomTrindade em outras palavras, a idéia do PASSWORD_DEFAULT é ser sempre o "melhor que tem no momento". Se você troca de PHP e vem coisa melhor, sua aplicação vai melhorar o hash automaticamente de cada usuário que se logar.

Comment: @Bacco nesse caso, somente dos usuários novos que criarem conta, certo? E ai para os antigos, só utilizar `password_needs_rehash` que ele se encarrega de atualizar tudo automaticamente. Correto?

Comment: @CelsomTrindade não irá atualizar sozinho o seu banco, ele só vai retornar um boolean e falar se precisa atualizar ou não. Veja na resposta que mostra o uso do `password_needs_rehash` tem explicado o fluxo em comentários.

Comment: @gmsantos sim sim, acabei me expressando mal. O que eu quis dizer foi justamente isso, de ele, automaticamente (sem precisar fazer alguma comparação manual), me retornar um valor indicando a necessidade de fazer um update na senha.

Comment: O `password_needs_rehash` não consegue fazer isso pois ele não sabe qual é a senha original que foi usada para gerar aquele hash. Por isso esse passo tem que ser feito ao efetuar o login, pois nesse momento você já comparou o input do usuário com o hash e sabe que ele é válido.

Comment: Resta mais alguma dúvida @CelsomTrindade? lembrando que o objetivo da resposta foi dar um norte ao como utilizar as funções de `password_*`. Caso tenha outras perguntas pontuais você pode tirá-la em uma nova pergunta :)

Answer (score 1):

Recomendaria ler este artigo: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#phpsourcecode

Acho interessante usar bcrypt com cost alto.
Até tem um código interessante na documentação do php para encontrar um cost aceitável:

```
/**
 * This code will benchmark your server to determine how high of a cost you can
 * afford. You want to set the highest cost that you can without slowing down
 * you server too much. 8-10 is a good baseline, and more is good if your servers
 * are fast enough. The code below aims for ≤ 50 milliseconds stretching time,
 * which is a good baseline for systems handling interactive logins.
 */
$timeTarget = 0.05; // 50 milliseconds 

$cost = 8;
do {
    $cost++;
    $start = microtime(true);
    password_hash("test", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ["cost" => $cost]);
    $end = microtime(true);
} while (($end - $start) < $timeTarget);

echo "Appropriate Cost Found: " . $cost . "\n";
```

Comment: Como dito acima, quanto ao uso eu já estou usando o `BCRYPT`, ao padrão `password_*` que o próprio php oferece. Mas a dúvida é a comparação deste com os demais métodos, como as técnicas de `md5` e `salt`, `PBKDF2`, e por ai vai..