# Problema com sistema de login - array

Tags: php, array, pdo, login, array-multidimensional

Olá. Estou criando um sistema de login para fins de estudo.

Identifiquei no me arquivo que não esta populando o array com as informações do banco de dados... e sim, ja me certifiquei que o email e senha informados ja existe na base de dados.

Segue arquivo de login.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'init.php';

// resgata dados digitados no formulario
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email']: '';
$senha = isset($_POST['senha']) ? $_POST['senha']: '';
// Cria o hash da senha
$seg_senha = password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// Verifica se os campos do form nao estao vazios
if(empty($email) || empty($senha)){
    echo 'Informe Email e Senha';
    exit;
}

// Comando no banco de dados
$pdo = db_connect();    // Abre conexão com o banco

$sql = "SELECT id, nome FROM usuarios WHERE email = :email AND senha = :senha";
// Cria query

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);    // Prepare da query

$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
// Atribui valor do campo email no valor email da query
$stmt->bindParam(':senha', $seg_senha);
// Atribui valor do campo senha no valor senha da query

$stmt->execute();   // Execute na query

$arr = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   // Cria array associativo

if(count($arr) <= 0){   // Verifica se existe elemento no array
    echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Login e/ou senha incorretos');window.location.href='../login.php';</script>";
    exit;
}

// Pega o primeiro usuario
$user = $arr[0];

// Inicia a sessão
session_start();
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id'];
$_SESSION['user_name'] = $user['nome'];

header('Location: ../index1.php');
```

Se eu comento da linha `if(count($arr) <= 0){` para baixo, e coloco um `var_dump($arr);`abaixo de `$arr = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` me retorna um array vazio

```
C:\wamp64\www\ProjetoALPHA\core\login.php:33:
array (size=0)
  empty
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Grato!

Comment: Não modifique a pergunta respondida, senão invalide a resposta. Abaixo tem dois trechos diferentes, um pra detectar senha errada separada de usuário errado, que é melhor para você testar. O outro trecho é para avisar do login errado, melhor para o dia a dia. Não dá para misturar os dois, ou usa um ou usa o outro. A negação é para inverter o resultado do teste, então tem que usar de acordo com o que está dentro do if e do else. Na dúvida, use como está, e só ajuste depois de entender.

Comment: Da ultima vez, quando respondi pra você, você tinha colado um código no Pastebin que eu já apontei os erros e corrigi, o problema já era de você ter misturado coisas. Estamos aqui pra ajudar, mas se você conseguir acompanhar as explicações, fica mais fácil. Quanto a ter tirado a aceitação, se é por que o código não atendeu, direito seu, mas é uma coisa que desincentiva a gente ajudar aqui, pois se não funcionou depois de todo tempo que eu gastei com você, grande chance de você não ter prestado atenção no que foi explicado. Inclusive pq eu só sai depois de vc confirmar que estava ok.

Comment: Sendo assim, se tiver alguma coisa concreta que possa passar, que não funcionou no código abaixo, pode até acrescentar no final da sua pergunta, ou mesmo perguntar nos comentários. mas sem mudar a parte que foi respondida já, senão vira uma bagunça. E não adianta encher de screenshots, pois só complica mais a postagem. Se tiver que por código, formate como código (e sem remover o original, senão estraga o que foi respondido e explicado).

Comment: @Bacco, eu não misturei as condições de if, simplesmente tentei uma que me passou, não funcionou, pois então tentei a outra que tinha me passado, visto que a segunda era diferente da primeira pelo sinal de negação. E eu tirei a aceitação, pois mesmo com a sua ajuda o código não funcionou como deveria, quando postei esta questão e lhe disse que estava ok era porque não tinha feito o teste de tentar logar com a senha errada. E quando tentei isso hoje, o sistema estava logando mesmo com a senha errada.

Comment: E não alterei a pergunta que foi feita, por isso inseri os sinais de igual ( === ) para separar a pergunta original, da dúvida de agora

Comment: Tente por como trecho de código, em vez de screenshot. Com trecho fica mais fácil para outros que forem ajudar também, e se for extenso já fica com scroll. Como screenshot nao dá nem pra pessoa copiar e colar pra testar.

Comment: Veja que isso nao é uma opinião minha, aqui tem uma lista de coisas que a comunidade em geral recomenda não fazer: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/70

Comment: Entendo. Mas os códigos dos prints são os mesmo que ja estão postados aqui como trecho de código...

Answer (score 5):

Isso aqui não vai praticamente gerar o mesmo hash que foi gravado no DB:

```
$seg_senha = password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

e, entre outras coisas, é por isso que a função é mais segura do que *hashes* simples. Além de usar *hashes* melhores, a função gera um *salt* aleatório a cada vez que é usada.

Sistemas primitivos e inseguros de senha eram feitos com esta técnica que está sendo testada na pergunta, e estes são vulneraveis a ataques de tabelas de senha pré calculadas.

Para entender melhor, veja esta postagem:

> [Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/70)

Para entender que não funciona, faça este teste:

```
echo password_hash( '123456', PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."<br>\n";
echo password_hash( '123456', PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."<br>\n";
echo password_hash( '123456', PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."<br>\n";
echo password_hash( '123456', PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."<br>\n";
echo password_hash( '123456', PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."<br>\n";
```

Confira no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/APcYzC)**.

Notou que a senha é a mesma, mas o *hash* muda? É por isso que gerando o *hash* novamente ao fazer o `SELECT` não adianta.

### Solução para o seu caso:

O correto é você recuperar os dados do DB com aquele usuário, e o *hash*, e só depois testar no PHP assim:

```
// ELIMINE ISSO DO LOGIN:
// $seg_senha = password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
// O password_hash só deve ser usado ao salvar uma senha, não ao ler.

$pdo = db_connect();
$sql = "SELECT id, nome, senha FROM usuarios WHERE email = :email";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email); // No caso o bindValue é mais adequado
$stmt->execute();

$arr = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if(count($arr) < 1) {
    ... USUARIO NAO EXISTE ...
} else if( password_verify( $senha, $arr[0]['senha'] ) ) {
    ... BEM VINDO AO SISTEMA ...
} else {
    ... SENHA ERRADA ...
}
```

Ou se não quiser dar a dica se foi o usuário ou a senha que erraram, para dificultar ataques, troque o final para

```
if( ( count($arr) < 1) || (!password_verify( $senha, $arr[0]['senha'])) ) {
    ... SENHA OU USUÁRIO ERRADO ...
} else {
    ... BEM VINDO ...
}
```

Em geral, é isso. Ajuste para o seu caso específico.

Manual:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.password-verify.php

Comment: Cuidado que tem muita besteira pela internet, se tiver duvida pergunte tambem. Tem gente que faz um monte de loucura, tipo MD5() de MD5(), coisa com base64() e outras coisas que só pioram a situação em vez de deixar mais seguro.

Comment: É, sei bem disso aí kk, acredito que pra situações mais basicas o password_hash serve muito bem

Comment: @Gabriel não só pras básicas. Quando usado certo, ele é bem robusto. Tem uma pergunta aqui no site com uma resposta muito boa, que ensina inclusive a fazer de uma maneira que sempre que atualize a segurança do PHP, todo usuário que renovar senha automaticamente tenha um hash melhor. Vou ver se acho o link e posto aqui pra vc

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/147319/70

Comment: Opa, mais um link que ira me ajudar então.. Não conheço muito ainda da parte de segurança pois ainda estou aprendendo PHP, que é a primeira linguagem que vou mais a fundo para aprender. Mas tenho certeza que esses dois links irão me servir bem no aprendizado... Obrigado!