# Email de confirmação com password_hash

Tags: php, mysql, criptografia

Ao se cadastrar no site, o usuário recebe um email de ativação do cadastro, até aí tudo certo. O problema está na verificação do password_hash, sei que tem o password_verify, mas nesse caso parece que não é possível utilizá-lo. A variável $key pega o id do usuário criptografado utilizando o password_hash.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Email de confirmação</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $key = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'key', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
        $verify = $conexao->prepare("select * from user where password_hash(id) = '$key'");
        $verify->execute();
        if($verify){
            $id = $verify->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $confirm = $conexao->prepare("update user set confirm = 1 where id = :id");
            $confirm->bindValue(':id', $id->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $confirm->execute();
            echo 'Cadastro ativado com sucesso!';
        }else{
            echo 'Erro ao ativar cadastro';
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Como demostrado acima, tentei verificar o id do usuário no banco, dessa forma:

```
$verify = $conexao->prepare("select * from user where password_hash(id) = '$key'");
```

E dessa forma também:

```
$verify = $conexao->prepare("select * from user where password_hash(id, PASSWORD_DEFAULT) = '$key'");
```

Mas como esperado deu erro: 'Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION password_hash does not exist', vi que dá para fazer desta forma com o MD5. É possível fazer algo parecido com isso com o password_hash?

Comment: O erro está na sua Query, `password_hash` é uma função do PHP, por isso está dando o erro de sintaxe. Faz o seguinte, pega o email para qual a mensagem de ativação foi  enviado, a partir dele você pega o `$id` cadastrado e usa o `password_verify` com o `$key`

Comment: `password_hash` é uma função do PHP. Ela não vai funcionar mesmo dentro de uma query. Talvez essa resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/147319/4751 te ajude.

Comment: Pois é Leandro, mas se eu fizer como MD5, assim por exemplo: $verify = $conexao->prepare("select * from user where MD5(id) = '$key'"); Funciona normal. queria saber se tem alguma função para o password_hash funcionar dentro de uma query, caso não tenha eu faço com MD5 mesmo.

Answer (score -1):

O erro está em sua Query. usando MD5(id) funciona porque o mysql tem está função implementada.
Você pode fazer o seguinte: encriptar o valor do id do usuário e então, comparar o hash gerado com o salvo no banco, ficando da seguinte forma:

```
    $key = password_hash(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'key', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS));
    $verify = $conexao->prepare("select * from user where id = '$key'");
    $verify->execute();
```

OBS: isso imaginando que o valor do GET "key" não seja um hash de fato, pois se estiver, não é necessário gerar novamente (pois daria diferente)

Comment: É uma boa ideia, mas no meu site vai dar problema, se eu criptografar o id, eu vou ter que fazer alteração em um monte de páginas do meu site, que estão puxando o id do usuário, porque o GET da url das páginas que pegam o id do usuário só pegam valor INT e o valor gerado pelo password_hash tem letras também.

Comment: Vou utilizar o MD5 mesmo, já que o mysql não tem nenhuma função imprementada para o  password_hash.

Comment: Só um adendo bem rápido, já que está usando o prepare, use o placeholder para proteger seu sql.
$conexao->prepare("select * from user where id = :id'");