# Logout PHP com cookies e sessions

Tags: php, session, login

Galera estou com um problema na hora de fazer o logout em meu site, pois quando uso somente sessions ele faz o logout normalmente, mas quando uso sessions e cookies para lembrar o usuário, preciso sair duas vezes, as vezes até mais, tipo fico na pagina do usuário e clico em sair, ele recarrega e ainda continua com o usuário, clico em sair de novo ai sim ele sai do usuário.

O botão que chama a função logout:

```
 <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="deslogar()">Desconectar</a></li>
```

Função JS:

```
     function deslogar(){
    $.post('/', {
        sair:'sair'
    });
    document.location.href="/";
}
```

Função PHP que ira chamar a function logout:

```
if(isset($_POST['sair'])){
        $logar = new SistemaLogin;
        $logar ->desconectar();
    }
```

Function logout php:

```
public function desconectar(){
        SistemaLogin::excluirCookies();
            session_destroy();
            header("Location: /cadastro_prof");
    }
```

function para deletar os cookies:

```
private function excluirCookies(){
            setcookie("email", "", time() - $this->tempo_cookie);
            setcookie('password', "", time() - $this->tempo_cookie);
            setcookie("tp_usuario", "", time() - $this->tempo_cookie);  
}
```

Eu crio as sessions e cookies assim, se o usuário não quer manter salvo seu login, o sistema cria somente as sessions, se não ele cria as sessions e os cookies:

```
private function criarSessions($pri_nm, $email, $senha, $tp_usuario){
        $_SESSION['pri_nome'] = $pri_nm;
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;
        $_SESSION['tp_usuario'] = $tp_usuario;
        $this->registrarLog();
    }

    private function criarCookies($email, $password, $tp_usuario){
         setcookie("email", $email, time()+$this->tempo_cookie, "/");
         setcookie('password', $password, time()+$this->tempo_cookie,"/");
         setcookie("tp_usuario", $tp_usuario, time()+$this->tempo_cookie, "/");
    }


    if($this->manter_online == 'sim'){
                        $this->criarCookies($this->email, $this->senha, $this->tp_usuario);
                        $this->criarSessions($this->pri_nm, $this->email, $this->senha, $this->tp_usuario);
                    }else{
                        $this->criarSessions($this->pri_nm, $this->email, $this->senha, $this->tp_usuario);
                    }
```

Coloquei o prazo nos cookies de 1 ano, e se sair ele subtrai o mesmo.

Comment: O que esse `sair: 'sair'` na sua primeira função? Não seria `data: `?

Comment: ele cria um post com o nome sair, coloquei o valor sair, mas isso não afeta em nada, pq o php so está pegando se a variavel 'sair' existe. eu crio o post e recarrego a pagina para o php pegar o arquivo.

Comment: se eu não me engano o data a gente usa em ajax, ai você pode criar um post com qualquer nome.

Comment: O método `excluirCookies()` está sendo executado normal? Coloca ali um `excluirCookies(){ exit('Chegou no excluirCookies');`.

Comment: Ele está excluindo os cookies sim, se eu colocar um exit na função excluirCookies(), ele não vai executar o session_destroy. Eu verifiquei em cookies salvo no chrome quando faço o primeiro logout, lá mostra que os cookies é valido até o final daquela seção. mas como matar os cookies e a sessão dele?

Comment: Está dando um refresh na página depois do método?

Comment: Então eu coloco o PHP para fazer isso, mas mesmo assim continua assim. Eu acho que assim devido na primeira vez eu apagar as sessions e os cookies, o próprio cookie crie suas sessions, chamo a função novamente, ele não apaga mais os cookies, pq já não tem mais e apaga as sessions deixada pelo cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nossa descobri o que era, criei uma Classe sistemaLogin, e uma function excluirCookies private e outra desconectar public, eu estava chamado uma função de dentro da classe da seguinte maneira: SistemaLogin::excluirCookies();
Coloquei assim: $this-> excluirCookies(); e funcionou, sacanagem isso né.
Perdi a noite ontem tentando descobrir o que era ¬¬.

Answer (score 0):

Coloque o *refresh* da página após o retorno do AJAX:

```
function deslogar(){
    $.post('/', {
        sair:'sair'
    }, function(data){
       if (window.location.origin == undefined)
          window.location.origin = '//' + window.location.host;
       document.location.href = window.location.origin;
    }, function(x,y,z){
       alert('Não foi possível sair');
       console.log(x,y,z);
    });
}
```

Tenha certeza que os *cookies* serão limpos:

```
private function excluirCookies(){
    unset($_COOKIE['email']);
    unset($_COOKIE['password']);
    unset($_COOKIE['tp_usuario']);
    setcookie('email', null, -1, '/');
    setcookie('password', null, -1, '/');
    setcookie('tp_usuario', null, -1, '/');  
}
```

<sub>[Excluir Coockies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19972329/3497987)</sub>

Notei que você armazena a senha em um *cookie* e isso é uma prática terrível, *cookies* podem ser roubados facilmente. Aqui tem uma pergunta e uma excelente resposta sobre como [Lembrar usuário com segurança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33664/lembrar-usu%C3%A1rio-com-seguran%C3%A7a).

Comment: eu uso criptografia na senha, uso o sha512, será que mesmo assim não fica seguro?

Comment: Vou tentar esse método, muito obrigado pela a ajuda!