# Login com Cookie ou Session no PHP5

Tags: php, session

Estou implementando uma área administrativa no meu site e sempre usei `$_SESSION` para fazer login. Porém, agora preciso que o login do usuário fique salvo caso ele sai da página.

> Minha dúvida: preciso usar o `$_COOKIE`para salvar as informações da `$_SESSION` ou posso usar somente o `$_COOKIE`?

Comment: Recomendo dar uma lida http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33664/lembrar-usu%C3%A1rio-com-seguran%C3%A7a/33684#33684

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar apenas `$_COOKIE`.

Você pode setar os valores em um `$_COOKIE` assim:

```
setcookie("loginCredentials", $user, time() * 7200); // expira depois de  2 hours
```

Para deslogar você  pode apenas deixar o valor do cookie em branco assim:

```
setcookie("loginCredentials", "");
```

E finalmente para verificar se o usuario esta logado:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['user']['id'] && !empty(isset($_COOKIE['user']['id']))){
// Usuário logado.
}else{
// Usuário não esta logado.
}
```

Essa variavel `$user` poderia ser algo assim:

```
$user = array(
    'id' => $id,
    'name' => $name,
    'login' => $login,
)
```

Só tenha cuidado para não deixar senhas e informações de forma desprotegida.

Comment: Valeu cara, ajudou muito ;)

Comment: O cookie não é menos seguro que a session?