# Login Seguro com Remember

Tags: php, session

Preciso de ajuda num script de login. O problema é que a *sessão* fica expirando automaticamente após um certo tempo de inatividade. Eu gostaria de aumentar o limite nativo da *sessão* das minhas páginas, pois o usuário precisa ficar conectado no sistema o dia inteiro, e ficar logando quando a *sessão* expira se torna um incomodo para os usuarios. Já tentei `session_cache_limiter(600);` para aumentar o limite, porem, no servidor não funciona, a *sessão* é destruída em 2 horas.

Meu script está basicamente assim, ao logar crio três `SESSION` conforme segue **logar.php**:

```
$_SESSION['cod_cliente'] = ($row["cod_cliente"]);
$_SESSION['op'] = ($row["usuario_id"]);
$_SESSION['op_tipo'] = md5($row["tipo"]); //perfil
```

Tenho uma página que checa se o usuário está logado **check.php**:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['cod_cliente']) && empty($_SESSION['cod_cliente']) || !isset($_SESSION['op']) || empty($_SESSION['op']) || !isset($_SESSION['op_tipo']) || empty($_SESSION['op_tipo']))
{
    session_unset();     
    session_destroy();
    header('Location:login.php');
}
```

E nas páginas que quero proteger coloco no inicio:

```
session_start();
include("check.php");
```

Comment: Creio que o seu sistema precise de algo como o "manter conectado" que aparece em vários logins, exemplo facebook. Sendo assim olhe esta resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33664/lembrar-usu%C3%A1rio-com-seguran%C3%A7a/33684#33684

Answer (score 2):

Desculpe o equivoco com a resposta anterior, não pude testar, daí deu erro.

Para trocar as configurações do `php.ini` sem editar o arquivo use a função [`ini_set()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ini-set.php) (algumas hospedagem bloqueiam tal função), use ela justamente para alterar o `gc_maxlifetime` da sessão, e para garantir use também [`session_set_cookie_params()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) que tem como primeiro parâmetro o `lifetime`.

Bolei um exemplo simples, onde defino a sessão com tempo máximo de 30 segundos, e até por isso uso [`session_cache_expire()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-cache-expire.php) para limpar meu `cache` depois de 1 minuto para realmente fechar minha sessão (só é preciso eliminar o `cache` quando o tempo da sessão é inferior á 180 minutos, pois a cada 180 minutos o `cache` é excluído por padrão). Seja o exemplo:

**index.php**:

```
<?php
    // define tempo de sessão para 30 seguntos (deve informar valor ente aspas)
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', '30');
    session_set_cookie_params('30');

    /* define a exclusão do cache após 1 minuto (apenas para a variável
       não ficar no cache por 180 minutos, para fazermos o tete) */
    session_cache_expire(1);

    session_start(); //inicia

    $_SESSION['logado'] = "Logado"; // Uma variável de teste

?>
<a href="verifica.php">Verificar</a>
```

**verifica.php**:

```
<?php
    session_start(); // pega sessão
    echo $_SESSION['logado']; // exibe variável de sessão (será exibido erro quando ela for apagada)
?>
```

Para testar é só acessar o `index.php`, após um minuto acessar `verifica.php` e a variável de sessão não vai estar definida. Ás vezes pode dar uma diferença por causa dos `cookies` de sessão que fica prendendo a variável na memória.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção. Coloquei "session_cache_expire(5);" no inicio da pagina conforme mencionou mas não desconectou, então presumo que também não irá estender o login para o limite que eu quiser. Estudei alguns tópicos e vi que na maioria o pessoal faz isso usando cookies mas não quero partir pra isso já que todos comentam sobre a vulnerabilidade de cookies

Comment: Pesquisei sobre o assunto e achei uma solução cabível, pelo menos aqui funcionou. Como citei, pode dar problema por causa dos cookies da sessão.

Answer (score 1):

Já enfrentei problemas em que colocava sessão por tempo ilimitado e ainda assim expirava após um período de inatividade e no meu caso era o Garbage Collector.

A configuração [gc_maxlifetime](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) do **php.ini** configura o tempo que uma sessão tem para ser considerada **descartável**, encerrando ela ainda que não tenha atingido o limite total.

Comment: É exatamente este o meu problema, porque qdo envio para o FTP do meu servidor é que isso acontece, ou seja, olhei no phpinfo e esta "session.gc_maxlifetime : 1440". Como não posso ter acesso em alterações no php.ini do servidor da hospedagem não está dando certo

Comment: `session.gc_maxlifetime : 1440` deve lhe dar uns 24m aproximadamente para a sessão ser expirar.Entre em contato com sua hospedagem e veja se eles podem fazer essa alteração para você, se não for possível talvez seja possível alterá-lo através de **ini_set** ou quem sabe até **.htaccess**.Em último caso troque a hospedagem.

Comment: Obrigado a todos pela atenção, vou verificar com a hospedagem