# É imprescindível o uso do captcha no formulário?

Tags: php, mysql, validação

Estou concluindo um formulário de cadastro, e tomei algumas precauções contra SQL injection. E por uma questão estética, não gostaria de inserir um captcha.

O formulário em questão é para cadastro de usuários, que farão login posteriormente.

Minha preocupação é que tive uma experiência, que acredito se enquadrar no termo "flood", onde eu ficava recebendo vários cadastros de um mesmo tipo, e como não tinha tratamento de dados, o robot mandava uns links...

Corro algum risco por não inseri-lo, é imprescindível ?

Comment: Usando captcha evita: flood, spam.

Comment: @Laerte tem como evitar isso sem captcha?Por uma questão estética..

Comment: Depende do formulário. Se for algo "largado" pela web, o captcha não evita umas empresas de segunda categoria de mandarem propaganda, pq são humanos que operam o sistema. Por outro lado, se for um formulário protegido por login, raramente precisa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem é uma escolha sua, você pode sofrer um ataque, vários bots fazendo várias requisições ao mesmo tempo, acredite acontece até um server pequeno que eu tenho passou por isso.

Você pode fazer o seguinte:
Limite o número de vezes que um determinado ip pode usar o formulário. 
Se um determinado usuário usar o formulário 5 vezes seguidas você mostra um captcha pra ele, só mostra se caso ele preencheu e fez a requisição várias vezes.

Comment: Boa, pode indicar um caminho, pra eu realizar esse procedimento...

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3571/qual-a-melhor-maneira-de-criar-um-sistema-de-login-com-php

Comment: vlw vou dar uma estudada...