# Explicação de código de validação de login e perfil

Tags: php, mysqli

EStou aprendendo php no entanto (não sei se é de costume de um iniciante) o código está ficando uma bagunça conforme eu vou tentando coisas novas.
Peguei umas aulas no youtube canal Celke no entanto apesar de ser bem didático algumas das vezes me parece algumas coisas desnecessárias quando comparo com outros códigos..
E no código a seguir estou tendo dificuldade para me organizar, alguêm poderia me ajudar a explica-lo?

O código a seguir valida o login **valida.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
//Incluindo a conexão com banco de dados
include_once("conexao.php");
//O campo usuário e senha preenchido entra no if para validar
if((isset($_POST['email'])) && (isset($_POST['senha']))){
    $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']); //Escapar de caracteres especiais, como aspas, prevenindo SQL injection
    $senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['senha']);
    $senha = md5($senha);

    //Buscar na tabela usuario o usuário que corresponde com os dados digitado no formulário
    $result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$usuario' && senha = '$senha' LIMIT 1";
    $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
    $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);

    //Encontrado um usuario na tabela usuário com os mesmos dados digitado no formulário
    if(isset($resultado)){
        $_SESSION['usuarioId'] = $resultado['id'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioNome'] = $resultado['nome'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] = $resultado['niveis_acesso_id'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioEmail'] = $resultado['email'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioEndereco'] = $resultado['endereco'];
        if($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "1"){
            header("Location: administrativo.php");
        }elseif($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "2"){
            header("Location: colaborador.php");
        }else{
            header("Location: cliente.php");
        }
    //Não foi encontrado um usuario na tabela usuário com os mesmos dados digitado no formulário
    //redireciona o usuario para a página de login
    }else{
        //Váriavel global recebendo a mensagem de erro
        $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuário ou senha Inválido";
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
//O campo usuário e senha não preenchido entra no else e redireciona o usuário para a página de login
}else{
    $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuário ou senha inválido";
    header("Location: index.php");
}?>
```

E a pagina do usuario **cliente.php**

```
<?php
 include_once("conexao.php");

session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['usuarioId'])) {
    $usuarioid = $_SESSION['usuarioId'];
    $nome_perfil = $_SESSION['usuarioNome'];
}


?>
```

Não sei se é pedir demais no entanto alguém poderia enxutar este código valida.php e me ajudar com a página do cliente.php de modo que eu possa introduzir informações do db na mesma, eu quero dispor dos cadastros realizado pelos usuários no entanto não sei como pegar a id do usuário junto com session_start. *Acho que a explicação de meu problema ficou tão confuso quanto o mesmo.

Comment: Jogue fora esse código, e dê uma pesquisada no site por alguma coisa baseada em password_hash e password_verify. Esse negócio de select comparando senha não faz sentido. Além disso, concatenar string para montar SQL é outra coisa bizarra, pesquise por SQL Injection e a função mysqli_bind_param para mesclar de uma maneira um pouco mais segura. Fora isso, normalmente não recomendo usar essa técnica de ficar redirecionando, mas se é pra fazer, lembre de sempre por um die(); após o redirecionamento para não ter efeitos colaterais (ao menos até ter uma razão real para deixar o script executando).

Comment: Esse `md5($senha)` resume o seu código, isto é quebrado desde 1994, se você está aprendendo então utilize tecnologias recentes e que atualmente são seguras, como BCrypt e Argon2, o primeiro é suportado pelo `password_hash()`. Usar `SELECT *` tende a ser mais lento, além disso não fica claro que você obtém, se fizer algo como `SELECT id, nome FROM ...` fica claro que você obtém essas duas colunas, sem precisar navegar pelo resto do código. Um outro problema é não ter número minimo de caracteres na senha, inclusive senhas em branco serão válidas. Sobre a organização, não vejo muitos problemas.

Answer (score 2):

Existem razões para você achar que talvez haja aí coisas desnecessárias, mas seria também correcto achar que faltam coisas necessárias.

Você poderia fazer assim:

```
<?php
session_start();
//Incluindo a conexão com banco de dados
include_once("conexao.php");
//O campo usuário e senha preenchido entra no if para validar
if((isset($_POST['email'])) && (isset($_POST['senha']))){
    $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']); //Escapar de caracteres especiais, como aspas, prevenindo SQL injection
    $senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['senha']);
    $senha = md5($senha);

    //Buscar na tabela usuario o id e nivel que corresponde com os dados digitado no formulário
    $result_usuario = "SELECT id, niveis_acesso_id FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$usuario' && senha = '$senha' LIMIT 1";
    $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
    $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);

    //Encontrado um usuario na tabela usuário com os mesmos dados digitado no formulário
    if(isset($resultado)){
        $_SESSION['usuarioId'] = $resultado['id'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] = $resultado['niveis_acesso_id'];
        if($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "1"){
            header("Location: administrativo.php");
            exit;
        }elseif($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "2"){
            header("Location: colaborador.php");
            exit;
        }else{
            header("Location: cliente.php");
            exit;
        }
    //Não foi encontrado um usuario na tabela usuário com os mesmos dados digitado no formulário
    //redireciona o usuario para a página de login
    }else{
        //Váriavel global recebendo a mensagem de erro
        $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuário ou senha Inválido";
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
    }
//O campo usuário e senha não preenchido entra no else e redireciona o usuário para a página de login
}else{
    $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuário ou senha inválido";
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
```

> exemplo usando prepared statements: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/vuQ2xMmZ)
>
> Leia isto também: [Qual a melhor forma de criar um sistema de login com php ?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3571/qual-a-melhor-maneira-de-criar-um-sistema-de-login-com-php/3604#3604)

Em vez de seleccionar todas as colunas referentes ao usuário, seleccione simplesmente o `id` e o `nivel` desse usuário, e na página *cliente* você verifica o `id` desse usuário e retorna as informações à partir de lá. E sempre que for usar o `header` para fazer redireccionamento, acompanhe-o sempre do `exit` para garantir que o script não fique executando, e acabe com problemas como *Headers Already Sent* e por aí.

## ...

No entanto, não use seu script dessa maneira, encriptar senha com `md5`, enviando todos os dados para a sessão, não verificando nem definindo `token`, ou mesmo sem encriptar ou codificar os valores da sessão, correspondendo directamente os dados que o usuário envia.

Até um `md5` + `salt` seria melhor que esse `md5` sozinho, mas isso seria também perda de tempo. Acontece que o php conta com a função [hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php), que implementa vários algoritmos de encriptação seguros e de fácil implementação, você pode começar por aí, depois podes ir  corrigindo várias outras coisas como *CRFS*, a própria *sessão* e outros. Existem várias perguntas aqui que poderão ter respostas as dúvidas irem surgindo, é só procurares.

Answer (score 0):

Uma sessão, $_SESSION, é uma maneira de armazenar informações (em variáveis) para serem usadas em várias páginas. Uma sessão é iniciada com a função session_start (). A função session_start () deve ser a primeira coisa no seu documento. Antes de quaisquer tags HTML.

A instrução include_once("conexao.php"); inclui e avalia o arquivo especificado durante a execução do script. Neste caso faz com que sua aplicação se conecte a um banco de dados. O arquivo conexao.php contém os dados de acesso do seu banco de dados MySQL. Os dados são:

- HOST: Host de conexão com o banco de dados.
- USUARIO: Usuário de acesso ao banco de dados da conexão;
- SENHA: Senha de acesso ao banco de dados especificado na conexão;
- BASE: Nome da base a qual você deseja fazer acesso.

A função isset () é usada para verificar se uma variável foi definida (existir) ou não, retornando true (verdadeiro) se definida e false (falso) quando não definida.

No mais, no seu código da pagina valida.php já existem vários comentários explicando detalhadamente cada passo.

> Para quem está começando a aprender isso é o basico e para finalizar é bom seguir as recomendações dos bruxos Bacco e Inkeliz. Até eu vou fazer isso pois estou desatualizadíssimo.