# Mostrar campo do bd na página web

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, query

Sou novata no desenvolvimento web, fiz um curso e estou usando como base o site que desenvolvemos lá.
Porém algumas coisas eu ainda não entendo bem e estou tendo problemas pra puxar o campo `nome` do banco de dados.
A conexão está correta, porém não sei como fazer isso.

```
    <?php
        if(!isset($_SESSION)){

            //redirecionamento
            header('location: index.php');
        }
        
            $email = $_SESSION['email'];
            $senha = $_SESSION['senha'];
            $consulta = $conexao->query('select id,nome,data_nascimento,email,senha from cadastro where email="'.$email.'" and senha=md5("'.$senha.'")');
            
            $lista=$consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            
            echo'<br>';
            echo'<main id="conteudo1">';
            echo'<p>Bem-Vinda, ','nome','!</p>';
            echo'</main>';
        ?>
```

Comment: Você tem que se preocupar com injeção de SQL, veja [Como acontece um SQL Injection?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100729/137387) e [Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-sql-no-meu-c%C3%B3digo-php). Também veja [Qual a melhor maneira de criar um sistema de login com PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3571/137387) e dê uma olhada nos exemplos da documentação do [PHP PDOStatement::fetchAll()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Answer (score -3):

Consegui resolver!!! Alterei apenas esses campos... O restante deixei como estava e funcionou. Obrigada!

```
$consulta = $conexao->query('select nome from cadastro where email="'.$email.'" and senha=md5("'.$senha.'")');
                
$lista=$consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo'<p>Bem-Vindo, ',$lista['nome'],'!</p>';
```